# DateTime : parsing unknown format

Tags: c#, datetime-format

The following code will output 2018-10-03 16:40:50 (instead of 2018-03-10) :

```
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime();
DateTime.TryParse("10/03/2018 4:40:50 PM", out dateTime );
MessageBox.Show(dateTime.ToString());
```

The following code will parse the date correctly (2018-03-10)

```
dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact("10/03/2018 4:40:50 PM", "dd/MM/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
MessageBox.Show(dateTime.ToString());
```

Is there any way to correctly parse this date without knowing the exact format?

The current culture of the server application is en-ca (English Canada) and I don't know the exact format of the string date to parse.  at least is there a way to parse the date without the curious swap between the month and day?  Sounds like an easy question but lost a lot of time reading and tried almost anything found here.

Thanks

Comment: How would you propose to interpret "09/03/18" - is that Sept 3, 2018 or is that March 9, 2018?

Comment: I think what you're looking for is `datetime.ToString("yyy-MM-dd");`

Comment: MM/DD/YY seems like a very unusual format...   Cant figure out where it assumes 10 is the month in 10-03-2018 ???

Comment: Just how many formats are actually used in the datasource? Maybe by using TryParse with styles? See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9h21f14e(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Is there any way to correctly parse this date without knowing the exact format? - No.

Comment: the short answer is no.  You need to know the culture of the date and you can use that to produce the results.  An example; We know that the UK goes by day, month, year so `DateTime.Parse("10/03/2018 4:40:50 PM", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-gb"));` parses it correctly.

Comment: en-gb works perfectly.... butwhy en-ca (english canada) , en-us (english us) is not working?

Comment: So nobody know why en-ca  / en-us is unable to parse the date (only on some system) while en-gb seems to works in any cases ??

Answer (score 1):

- End up using TryParseExact with an array list of known format. (ugly but it work)
- There is no way to detect MM-DD-YYYY versus DD-MM-YYYY.  Known limitation (this format is finally not supported by our application)

Thanks!